# How to disable error messages output by python-vlc MediaPlayer object?

Tags: python, libvlc, python-vlc

I can't seem to figure out how to stop error messages from a python-vlc MediaPlayer object being printed to the console.

I've tried the following without success:
`self.vlc_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("--verbose=-1)`
`self.vlc_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("--verbose -1")`

`self.vlc_player.set_mrl(song_url, "--verbose=-1")`
`self.vlc_player.set_mrl(song_url, "--verbose -1")`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry if I'm late, but if you are still searching for the answer...
You can use something like this when initiating the VLC instance:

```
import vlc
    
instance = vlc.Instance()
instance.log_unset()
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.environ['VLC_VERBOSE'] = '-1'` or `'-2'` seems to work in Linux, but might be appropriate to restore it on program exit:

https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/119#issuecomment-571793477

Upd.: No need to restore, it is only set for the current process and its potential children (https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/issues/119#issuecomment-571796331)